# Ordered tests in windows phone testing framework

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, wp7test

I use WP7Test nuget package to launch my tests.
I have a two tests, for login and payment operations. I need to launch test for login and save a session. Then i need to launch payment test. As i know, by default tests runs in random order.

Is there any way to force them to run in my order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. By design, UnitTest are meant to run in parallel (or random in your case). This is because the system wants to sandbox each UT to prevent the very thing you are trying to do (which is have other unit tests effecting the system's state).

My recommendation would be to have a helper "login" function that both your login and payment UT call. This should basically the be logic you already have in your login test, minus the assert call.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WP7Test (if memory serves me correctly) is really only meant to unit test.

Unit tests are intended to design the absolute minimal pieces of code, never anything the reads or writes to an outside source. (in your case session) there are a number of types of tests suited for that situation functionality and integration tests come to mind...

You could write one test the covers both functions in one test in order, but again that's not really unit testing...

For the quick Integration Testing you could simply do this... (People are going to cringe at this, but it will serve your purposes)

```
   [TestMethod]
   private void FunctionalityBeingTested_ConditionBeingTested_ExpectedOutput()
   {
        //input used by your first method
        //Method that writes to your session
        //input used by your second method
        var session = //Method that reads from your session
        //whatever assertions are appropriate for your expected results...
        //what you expect your results to be...
        Assert.IsNotNull(session);
        Assert.IsEqual(expected, session);
    }
```

Once more, this is not a unit test, it's an integration or functionality test depending on the scope. You're testing more than a single step in your implementation, you should unit test everything you can, but anytime you're dealing with something outside the direct control of your app it's no longer a unit test.

I would strongly recommend if you aren't already, you should look into Dependency Injection for testing Windows Phone Apps. I'm a Windows Phone developer myself and can say proper testing is like pulling teeth without it. (Interfaces, Fakes, Moqs, etc are amazing tools for testing)